# 'inline-block' div with max-width is wider than necessary after a line break

Tags: jquery, html, css

Consider this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SnhDX/2/

As you can see, the red `inline-block-1` div takes up more space than necessary for the text to fit. **Is there any way to remove the empty part, so it looks like green `inline-block-2` (without removing the `max-width` and without hard-coding `width`)?** jQuery is allowed, but CSS/HTML-only solution preferred.

Image for reference. The red one is wrong, the green one is right:

[image]

Comment: you have `max-width:100px;` on the div, remove this and it will collapse like the green one above.

Comment: The fiddle you posted is not what your screenshot shows.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Oops, really sorry about the fiddle being wrong. Fixed it.

Comment: remove max-width and set its width to the width of the second div

Comment: I need to keep `max-width` set.

Comment: **The red one is wrong** i don't think so. green one will have different css.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky.

The closest I was able to get the two divs to match is by inserting a `<br>` in `inline-1` right after "Ipsum". The culprit is the whitespace between "Ipsum" and "This". When the text wraps at the indicated 100px, it keeps everything that will fit - including the space between those two words. The only thing that can trump a hard whitespace is setting an explicit width to make it wrap, or getting rid of it. Inserting a `<br>` instead of a space eliminates that whitespace, though they're still a few px off in my browser.

I hate to be that guy, but this seems unnecessarily complicated - what's requiring this setup?  It's really irregular that you can't change explicit widths unless you're working with `float`s. Maybe there's a way to simplify this and make life easier on yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue with vertical sizing.  See if adding this CSS helps:

```
overflow:hidden
```

Best of luck!
-Brendan

Answer (score -1):

If you must keep `max-width: 100px` then just set a width equal to the width of the "correct" container then they will both be the same size.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnhDX/5/)

Comment: But won't this make `max-width` completely irrelevant? I've updated my question: `width` must not be hard-coded.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the width has to be what ever the width of the second div is, be it 81px or 1000px?

Comment: No, I'm sorry for not being clear. I don't want that empty space to the right of the text. I want the div to be only as wide as the text.

Comment: Because you have the div set to `display: inline-block;`  the div therefore has a `width` of `100%`. In addition, you have set `max-width: 100px`. The only thing close to that would be to asign `inline-block-1` the property `white-space: nowrap;`. But that looses the `max-width` property. If you want the div to look like the second one you will have to assign a width.